# Silverlight controls in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I need my ASP.NET web application to use silverlight controls in my web page. Please let me know how to use them. Do i need to add any reference for them in my Visual Studio 2005. Framework 2.0 and ASP.NET 2.0 application environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice post over [here](http://blogs.sqlxml.org/bryantlikes/archive/2007/05/02/silverlight-hello-world-in-c-from-vs-2005.aspx) which takes care of your problem.

Cheers.