# How to add Silverlight controls in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have downloaded the silver light from this http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight//

I need to use this as custom toolbox in my Visual studio please let me know how to add this
and use the controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143281/silverlight-controls-in-aspnet-application#143317) may help you. This actually takes you to a post which I previously answered. Just go to the answers section and click on the link.